# ImportError when importing Python module written in C in cloned Git repo

Tags: python, c, python-import, nipy

I've just cloned the [NiPy repository](https://github.com/nipy/nipy), but when I try to import `nipy.algorithms.registration`, I get the following error:

```
In [1]: import nipy.algorithms.registration
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-17bae03bf7b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import nipy.algorithms.registration

/home/despo/dbliss/nipy/nipy/algorithms/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 __docformat__ = 'restructuredtext'
      8 
----> 9 import statistics
     10 import fwhm, interpolation, kernel_smooth, diagnostics
     11 

/home/despo/dbliss/nipy/nipy/algorithms/statistics/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 __docformat__ = 'restructuredtext'
      7 
----> 8 from . import intvol, rft, onesample, formula
      9 from ._quantile import _quantile as quantile, _median as median
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name intvol
```

I discovered that there are two files called intvol in the repository: intvol.c and intvol.pyx.  What's going on?

### SOLVED: See first comment below.

Comment: You have to compile first. `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` (or use a package manager such as `pip`).

Comment: Well `pip`, right, I don't want to use, because I want to install the repo from GitHub, up through the most recent commit -- not the version of the package that `pip` has.  But you're saying saving the repo locally and putting it in my PYTHONPATH isn't enough?  I need to run `setup.py`?  What exactly needs to be compiled that isn't able to be compiled during the import (as normally happens when I import a module, and a .pyc file is automatically created)?

Comment: That did the job for me, @larsmans, thanks!  I suppose I'll have to run `setup.py` like this every time I pull.